# Looking for QGIS equivalent of ArcGIS "Convex Hull" and "Circle" under Minimum Bounding Geometry (Data Management)

Tags: qgis, qgis-3, qgis-processing, convex-hull

I have the opportunity to run ArcGIS and QGIS side by side for a few months and was looking to see what comparisons there are.

So I'm interested to know if there is a similar tool on QGIS?

Comment: You have not searched very intensively so far, or have you? For the convex hull see Vector - Geoprocessing tools - Convex hull(s). Or Processing toolbox - Vector geometry tools - Convex hull.

Comment: Yes, you are right. It is there. It was very late at night when I went looking. I did also ask Dr Google as well as search here too, before I posted. Apologies for wasting time.

Comment: QGIS does not seem to have Minimum Bounding Circle. You can put your data into PostGIS and use http://postgis.net/docs/ST_MinimumBoundingCircle.html or use OpenJUMP which does have such tool.

Comment: Please, do not forget about ["What should I do when someone answers my question?"](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, there is the ["Convex hull"](https://docs.qgis.org/3.16/en/docs/user_manual/processing_algs/qgis/vectorgeometry.html#convex-hull), located under `Vector > Geoprocessing tools > Convex hull`.